# PRISM controlling external devices

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tcp, prism

I plan to use the PRISM libraries for a project running on a PC that controls one or multiple instruments and visualizes and stores the data of the device(s) and lets the user enter some control data. The devices have various digital and analog sensors and actors. They can be of different type and intelligence. Most often they have no 'real' intelligence and all the control logic sits in the PC. 
This 'intelligence' needs to be constantly reading the data from a device. The communication can be of various kind, like a COM port, TCP/IP socket, HTTP to a web interface, etc.

I am not sure what's the best solution for that 'intelligent logic'. Since it needs a continuous communication with the device, it needs to be separated from all the UI tasks. It will need some kind of state-machine in a background worker or thread to build the higher process logic.

Question: Should it be an instance per device registered in PRISM as a service with a reference to that background worker? Or should that background worker be created and linked to the ViewModel I need for each configured instrument to handle it's data to show and edit? Or is there another best solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think this si more general architecture question than a specific PRISM one...

I've done something similar with other MVVM framework and my solution was based on a single listener (I had only TCP sockets to coomunicate with instruments) registerd as a service. In your application you can either have multiple queues or a single queue with multiple producers.

All messages from the devices were inserted in a concurrent queue and each ViewModel (one for each device) read from that queue.

Communication from ViewModel to device happened directly without going through an "output" queue.

The whole application was build on await/async pattern to decouple UI from communication. I was able to send and receive multiple commands and notifications from serval devices at the same time without any issue.

But again this is really a broad question and mine is a broad answer lot of things depend of how you have to interact with dvices. My solution balances complexity with flexibility, but a lot of other architectures are available.

Comment: thx for your answer, Antonello. I prefer not to install a Windows service and thought more of a shared service in PRISM. But yes, the question can be seen as quite general architecture too

Comment: The pattern I've suggested can be also used with a shared communication service in PRISM, just implement it with a background worker. I prefer this single listener architecture because it is easyer to debug communication issues when they arise.